# How to avoid setting CSS class to one table among two tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table having id `outerTable`.

Inside the first table there is another table having id `innerTable`.

I want a class to be applied to even rows of `outerTable` only.

I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var i, j, tables, rows;

        tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

        for ( i = 0; i < tables.length; i += 1 ) {
            rows = tables[i].rows;

            for ( j = 0; j < rows.length; j += 1 ) {
                rows[j].className = j % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd';
            }
        }
    });
```

But the class applies to both tables then.

In above code I tried using :

```
tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table #outerTable');
```

But it does not work.

Here is my HTML/PHP code:

```
<table border="0" id="outerTable" cellspacing="0">
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($agent_res))
    {
    ?>
<tr valign="top">
    <td width="200px"><?php echo $row['agent_name']; ?></td>
    <td width="100px;"><?php echo $row['port']; ?></td>
    <td width="200px"><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <table align="left" id="innerTable">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Contact</b></td>
                <td>: </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['contact']; ?>      </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Email ID</b></td>
                <td>: </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email_id']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Telephone</b></td>
                <td>: </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['tel']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Fax</b></td>
                <td>: </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['fax']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Website</b></td>
                <td>: </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['website_address']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
    }
    ?>  
</table>
```

So please can any one help me out to resolve this issue.

Here is the jsFiddle for the situation: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/21/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your style selectors as

```
#outerTable > tbody > tr > td
```

and

```
#outerTable > tbody > tr.even > td
```

See [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/30/)

Comment: Thank you it works. You have solved my two problems i also wanted to remove those inner table border-left and border-bottom. Again Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$("#outerTable tr:not(#innerTable tr)").each(function(){

if($(this).index() % 2==0)
{
$(this).addClass("evenTest");

}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you hvae jquery, Simply use the following code to get only `OuterTable` :

```
var table = $('#outerTable')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the background-color you can add this CSS

```
#outerTable tr.odd td td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/28/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS rule

```
.outerTable>tr>td{   }

.outerTable>tr.even>td { }
```

Answer (score -1):

add following to your css definition:

```
#innerTable td {
    background: white !important;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/24/